# How can I run my Javascript OnClientClick and C# OnClick without postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclick, onclientclick

I have a div that acts as a popup in my master page called 'mydiv-clear'.
I have my main page content inside the div 'fade'.

I am able to successfully "popup" my div (change display from none to block) with Javascript OnClientClick if I use "return false;" in my OnClientClick to prevent postback (div goes back to display:none on postback).

I want to perform C# OnClick control for extra functionality within my popup. When I have return=false; in my OnClientClick I am not able to hit my C# OnClick code. When I remove return=false; my page is posted back and my display is back to display=none;. Solutions online suggested moving my button into an UpdatePanel control or to use UseSubmitBehaviour=false but neither of these have worked for me.

The below solution when I break through my code will fire my javascript (popup appears) cause a postback (popup disappears) and fire my C#. Can someone suggest a way to prevent postback and still fire C#? Thanks

.Net

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOptOut" OnClientClick="div_show();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnOptOut_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Opt Out" />
```

C#

```
protected void btnOptOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                try
                {

                    _dal.createOptOutRecord(_myuser.id, _myuser.EmailAddress);

                    //More functionality to go here

                }

                catch(Exception ex)
                {


                }
            }
```

Javascript

```
 function div_show() {
    document.getElementById('mydiv-clear').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('fade').style.opacity = ".1";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postback will always be executed on the button `OnClick` event. Even if it is in an UpdatePanel it will still do a (partial) postback. But an UpdatePanel can still work as long as the div is on the outside.

But there are multiple ways to keep the visibility of the div. First example uses `RegisterStartupScript`

```
    protected void btnOptOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call the div_show() function again after postback
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showDiv", "div_show()", true);
        //or set the visibility directly to the div after postback
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showDiv", "document.getElementById('mydiv-clear').style.display = \"block\";", true);
    }
```

The second example uses a global variable.

```
    public string divVisibility = "none";
    protected void btnOptOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divVisibility = "block";
    }
```

and then in .aspx file

```
    <div id="mydiv-clear" style="display: <%= divVisibility %>">myDiv</div>
```

The third example with an `UpdatePanel` in the .aspx page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOptOut" OnClientClick="div_show();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnOptOut_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Opt Out" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Does it work?"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="mydiv-clear" style="display: none">myDiv</div>
```

And then in code-behind.

```
    protected void btnOptOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Yes it does!";
    }
```